# Set Frame Margin for Exporting Video File (.avi)

Tags: animation

I have a question regarding setting the frame margins of exporting .avi file.
I want to make a short video of some pictures I import using Table:

```
table1 = Table[
[Show[Import[ToString[i] <> ".eps"], ImageSize -> Large], {i, 1, 100, 1}];
```

These pictures are all fine with 0 image padding, but when I try exporting them to video:

```
Export["1.avi", table1, ImageSize -> Large, 
"FrameRate" -> 4],
```

And the video cuts them off, as if only showing a thin stripe of the whole pictures. I tried messing with ImagePadding, but that only puts the pictures in the video in the bottom left corner. Is there a way to show the pictures in the video at the center of the screen, when playing? Thank you very much.